# Not able to get the parameter send in the router in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my Ionic 4 project, I am sending the parameter using the router but I am not able to get the parameter in the other page.

This is my **tabs.router.module.ts**:

```
{
    path: 'tab2',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'eventdetails',
        loadChildren: '../eventdetails/eventdetails.module#EventdetailsPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'acceptchallenge/:chid',
        loadChildren: '../acceptchallenge/acceptchallenge.module#AcceptchallengePageModule'
      }
    ]
},
```

This is my **tab2.page.ts**:

```
acceptchallenge(challengesobj)
{
 console.log('Accept Challenge:', challengesobj);
 this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2/acceptchallenge/' + challengesobj.id,challengesobj]);
}
```

In this ts, I am sending the `challengesobj` to the other page but I am not able to get it.

This is my **accept.page.ts**:

```
export class AcceptchallengePage implements OnInit {
  chaobj: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  async ionViewWillEnter(){
    let me=this;  
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      me.chaobj = params['challengesobj']; 
    });
    console.log('challengesobj: ', me.chaobj);
  }
}
```

In this ts file, when I console the value, it is showing undefined.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what does the `params` show ?

Comment: @SachinGupta.  This challengesobj params is the obj that I am sending and It is showing undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try It:**

**Sending object:**

```
acceptchallenge(challengesobj)
{

let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: {
    special: JSON.stringify(challengesobj)
  }
};

 this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2/acceptchallenge/' + challengesobj.id,navigationExtras]);
}
```

**Getting object:**

```
 export class AcceptchallengePage implements OnInit {
      chaobj: any;
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
           if (params && params.special) {
               this.chaobj = JSON.parse(params.special);
               console.log('challengesobj: ', this.chaobj);
           }
        });
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Another way:**

**Sending object:**

```
acceptchallenge(challengesobj)
{

let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: {
    challengesobj: challengesobj
  }
};

 this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2/acceptchallenge/' + challengesobj.id,navigationExtras]);
}
```

**Getting object:**

**Getting object:**

```
 export class AcceptchallengePage implements OnInit {
      chaobj: any;
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

         this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
              this.chaobj = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.challengesobj;
          }
       });
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Showing undefined. Should I have to define in the routes also.

Comment: path: 'acceptchallenge/:chid', I have defined the Id, so I am getting the id but not the 'challengesobj'